# Losing focus in an exam, how does it affect my goal - grad school

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, exams

So I'll explain my self briefly, I've just finished my first semester in my undergrad program and my goal is to move on to masters in the US in Stanford or near that area.

So obviously grades are very important and here's the problem, I'm putting the hours in throughout all the semester (easily 10 hours a day, sometimes longer) and I don't have  issues with understanding nor with executing what was learned but come the day of the exam and I do TERRIBLY and I can't explain why, I don't know whether it's because of stress  or something else and I feel lost as everyone I score a B instead of an A I feel like my grad school goal is only getting further away from me.

I'd appreciate any tips or ideas with how to deal with this.
I'm currently retaking all the tests to improve my grades but it's exhausting because the material is not the problem...

In case it matters, I'm talking about computer science.

*if the title is inappropriate please let me know how to change it*

Thank you

Edit: my topic is different from the one  mwhombat linked to because where I live you don't get to pick your courses I can't focus on project based courses some have then but most don't so I HAVE to get better at test taking

Comment: You say you can't explain why you do badly in exams, but the title of your question says that you lose focus in exams- could it be the two are connected? Do you need advice on test taking in general or more specific advice on how to improve your concentration in an exam?

Comment: I just had nothing too specific to say, but in general:    I usually black out and forget trivial actions but I wouldn't say I'm losing focus in the sense of thinking if something that is not the exam at times I'm just freaking out to the point my hand is shaking and I can feel how I'm never going to reach my goals  (I'm sorry if this is not the right forum for this)

Comment: "because where I live you don't get to pick your courses" If prior postings that seem to answer your question are not applicable because of your geographic specifics, you really need to put geographic specifics into your question.  Otherwise you're wasting everyone's time...especially your own.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize it matters. I'm from Israel

Comment: I would try to find some of your class mates, that are performing very well on the tests and ask them for some advice. If you don't know anyone yet that is performing very well, this is a great opportunity to make some new friends. Taking tests is really an art form all of its own, and I'm sure those in your class that score highly will have some insights they could share with you about how to sit a test well. Also ask your faculty if they have old papers, you could practice with, you might also ask a member of the teaching staff to perhaps do a mock invigilation with you also.

Comment: "I usually black out and forget trivial actions but I wouldn't say I'm losing focus in the sense of thinking if something that is not the exam at times I'm just freaking out to the point my hand is shaking and I can feel how I'm never going to reach my goals."  If you put this in the question, you may get it reopened.  Test anxiety is an issue for grad students as well. // Short answer: tell a medical provider and an academic advisor about what you experience.  Both may have resources to offer.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to find some of your class mates, that are performing very well on the tests and ask them for some advice. Regarding what sources they are specifically studying, how they decide what material to prep for the exam and what not to etc.

If you don't know anyone yet that is performing very well, this is a great opportunity to make some new friends. Taking tests is really an art form all of its own, and I'm sure those in your class that score highly will have some insights they could share with you about how to sit and prepare for a test well.

Also ask your faculty if they have old papers, you could practice with, you might also ask a member of the teaching staff to perhaps do a mock invigilation for you, with an old paper, and give you feedback about how you did, and where it fell short. Practice makes perfect.

Also isolate the reason you are not doing well in the tests. Is it because you simply do not know the answers? Or are you running out of time? Or are you not reading the question properly under exam conditions? Once you know this you will be in a better position to develop a strategy to improve in the key areas that are impacting your scores.